# Golden Section Method in C

Tags: c, gsl

I am pretty new to coding and I have been having an impossible time trying to find online help writing a C code that will use the golden section method (which apparently the GNU Scientific Library has, although I haven't had any luck finding it) to find the minimum of functions that Newton's method of minimization fails for.

Specifically I want to input an x-value as a starting point and have the code output the function's minimum value and the x coordinate of the minimum value point. My function is f(x) = x<sup>20</sup>. I am also allowed some error (< 10<sup>-3</sup>).

I don't even know where to begin with this, I have been ALL over the internet and haven't found anything helpful. I would seriously appreciate some help as to where I might find more information, or how I might implement this method.

Edit:

This is my code as of now:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>  /* Defines GSL_SUCCESS, etc. */
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_min.h>

int minimize_convex(gsl_function *F,double a, double b, double *x_min, double tol)
{
    int status;
    double h = (b - a) * .0000001;   /* Used to test slope at boundaries */
    /* First deal with the special cases */
    if (b - a < tol)
    {
        *x_min = b;
        status = GSL_SUCCESS;
    }
/* If the min is at a, then the derivative at a is >= 0.  Test for
 * this case. */
else if (GSL_FN_EVAL(F, a + h) - GSL_FN_EVAL(F, a) >= 0)
{
    *x_min = a;
    status = GSL_SUCCESS;
}
/* If the min is at b, then the derivative at b is >= 0.  Test for
 * this case. */
else if (GSL_FN_EVAL(F, b - h) - GSL_FN_EVAL(F, b) >= 0)
{
    *x_min = b;
    status = GSL_SUCCESS;
}
else
{
    /* Choose x_guess so that it's value is less than either of the two
     * endpoint values. Since we've got this far, we know that at least
     * of of F(a + h) and F(b - h) has this property. */
    double x_guess;
    x_guess = (GSL_FN_EVAL(F, a + h) < GSL_FN_EVAL(F, b - h)) ? 
        a + h : b - h;
    int iter = 0, max_iter = 200;
    const gsl_min_fminimizer_type *T;
    gsl_min_fminimizer *s;
    T = gsl_min_fminimizer_goldensection;
    s = gsl_min_fminimizer_alloc(T);
    gsl_min_fminimizer_set(s, F, x_guess, a, b);

    do
    {
       iter++;
       status = gsl_min_fminimizer_iterate(s);  /* perform iteration */
       status = 
           gsl_min_test_interval(a, b, tol, 0.0); /* |a - b| < tol? */

       a = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_lower(s);
       b = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_upper(s);

       if (status == GSL_SUCCESS)
       {
           *x_min = gsl_min_fminimizer_x_minimum(s);  /* current est */
       }
    }
    while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < max_iter);

    gsl_min_fminimizer_free(s);
}
return status;
}
double f(double x, void *params)
{
    double *p = (double *) params;
    return (x^(50)) + *p;
}
double C = 0.0;
int main (void)
{
    double m = 0.0, result;
    double a = -1.0, b = 1.0;
    double epsilon = 0.001;
    int exit_val;
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &f;
    F.params = &C;
    exit_val = minimize_convex(&F, a, b, m, &result, epsilon);
    printf("Minimizer: %g\n", result);
    printf("Function value: %g\n", f(result, &C));
    printf("%d\n", exit_val);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:
try.c:69:14: error: invalid operands to binary
      expression ('double' and 'double')
    return (x^(50)) + *p;

try.c:81:54: error: too many arguments to function
      call, expected 5, have 6
    exit_val = minimize_convex(&F, a, b, m, &result, epsilon);

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you look at gsl_root_fsolver_bisection() ? https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Root-Bracketing-Algorithms.html#Root-Bracketing-Algorithms

Comment: GSL Reference Manual: [Minimization Algorithms](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Minimization-Algorithms.html#index-golden-section-algorithm-for-finding-minima)

Comment: wikipedia has some examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search

Answer (score 2):

[gsl](/questions/tagged/gsl) has a generic minimizer that can use multiple methods to acheive the minimization.  The description of how to use the minimizer can be found in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/One-dimensional-Minimization.html).  You can set it to the golden section method by delcaring the method as `gsl_min_fminimizer_goldensection`.

Comment: @Carly You'll need to write [tag:C] code that refers to the library.  Take a look at their [example code](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Minimization-Examples.html), and tweak it to your needs.

Comment: @Carly No, you won't be able to do all this from the terminal.  Fire up you favorite plain text editor (vi, emacs, notepad, ...) and compiler.

Comment: I just wasn't sure how to compile the code in terminal but I figured it out! Would you mind taking a look at the code I posted?

Comment: @Carly `x^50` doesn't do what you think it does.  You want `pow(x,50)`.  This function is in the math library.  I expect that gsl references it, but you should probably iunclude `#include <math.h>` at the top, just to be safe.

Comment: @Carly The other error is because the variable that holds your initial guess doubles as the solution.  use `exit_val = minimize_convex(&F, a, b, &m, epsilon);`, and replace all occurances of `result` in `main` with `m`.

Comment: @Carly Look for `^` [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).  It does a bitwise exclusive or.

Comment: I think that got rid of all of the errors and I compiled it using Terminal! Thank you so much. My final question is how do I run it using Terminal?

Comment: @Carly What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: OSX, and I compiled using gcc @Degustaf

Comment: @Carly Based on gcc's standard output, the command is `./a.out`.  If it tells you it can't find the command, you'll need to change you're permissions with the command `chmod 755 a.out`.